# Optimise "COUNT(DISTINCT col) WHERE othercol = ?" for speed

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I have a distinct count that takes about half a minute or more to get the result.

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT ip) as unique_visits
from idevaff_iptracking
where acct_id = ? and stamp = ?
```

What would be the faster way to count the IPs? There are indexes on ip column and on acct_id with ip column.

Comment: Perhaps if you could echo the resulting query, and provide SHOW CREATE TABLE statements and the EXPLAIN for the given quer(y/ies) - but I suspect that there's not a lot of room for improvement here.

Comment: I so hoped there is a way to make it faster. It takes ages sometimes... I guess I can show what you ask for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT ip) as unique_visits
from idevaff_iptracking
where acct_id = ? and stamp = ?
```

You want an index on `idevaff_iptracking(acct_d, stamp, ip)`.

Comment: I can give that a try. Thanks! I already have an index acct_id_ip(acct_id,ip) and separate index of ip(ip).

Comment: I think that did it. Now it is noticeably like 10, sometimes even 20, times faster!! Which reminded me on how indexes are utilized by MySQL. Thanks for this!